# Symfony 3 - Sending AJAX request as XmlHttpRequest() (javascript) does not pick up request as XmlHttpRequest in backend

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, symfony

I have an `ExceptionListener` implemented in Symfony3 (also works in Symfony2). The `ExceptionListener` identifies whether the request was normal HTTP or AJAX (XmlHttpRequest) and generates a response accordingly. When using jQuery `.post()` or `.ajax()`, the `ExceptionListener` returns `$request->isXmlHttpRequest()` as TRUE, but when using javascript `var xhr = new XmlHTTPRequest()`, the `ExceptionListener` returns `$request->isXmlHttpRequest()` as FALSE. I am using the latter in a small amount of instances where files need to be uploaded via AJAX (which cannot be done using `.post()` or `.ajax()`.

I am looking for a solution (either frontend or backend) to resolve my `ExceptionListener` incorrectly picking this up as a normal HTTP request.

**Frontend Code:**

```
function saveUser()
{
    var form = document.getElementById('userForm');
    var formData = new FormData(form);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open('POST', '{{url('saveUser')}}', true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function (node) 
    {  
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) 
        {  
            if (xhr.status === 200) 
            {  
                var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                if (typeof(data.error) != 'undefined')
                {
                    $('#processing').modal('hide');
                    $('#errorMsg').html(data.error);
                    $('#pageError').modal('show');

                }
                else
                {
                    $('#successMsg').html('User Successfully Saved');
                    $('#processing').modal('hide');
                    $('#pageSuccess').modal('show');
                    $('#userModal').modal('hide');
                    updateTable();
                }
            } 
            else 
            {  
                console.log("Error", xhr.statusText);  
            }  
        }  
    };
    $('#processing').modal('show');
    xhr.send(formData);

    return false;
}
```

**ExceptionListener.php (partial)**

```
# If AJAX request, do not show error page.
if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest())  # THIS RETURNS FALSE ON JS XmlHTTPRequest()
{
    $response = new Response(json_encode(array('error' => 'An internal server error has occured. Our development team has been notified and will investigate this issue as a matter of priority.')));
}
else
{       
    $response = new Response($templating->render('Exceptions/error500.html.twig', array()));
}
```

Comment: have you tried checking for $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']?

Comment: $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] returns 'XmlHTTPRequest' on .post() and .ajax() - "Undefined index" both normal HTTP request and on javascript new XmlHTTPRequest() - So same issue (unable to distinguish that new XmltHttpRequest() is in fact an AJAX request).

Comment: then when using the vanilla ajax pass a X-Requested-With header to your ajaxed page

Comment: @sakhunzai Your reply was ZERO help

Comment: why aren't you sending files via jquery $.ajax function?

Comment: @Magnanimity  re-read your comment and think about it. when you are being helped and guided by hundreds of people commenting like this show a lot about yourself. Most of SO help you get here is free and out of goodwill so do not be arrogant. If you have not learned something I have learned something new from your question, that is philosophy of learning.

Comment: @sakhunzai I have been a developer basically all my life (since I was 10), most recently I have been a web developer for about 8 years. When I post a question it is because I have identified a problem, I have read up on the manuals, I have searched for the issue in forums, and were unable to find a solution. Your comment with "stock standard manual links" suggest that I am so ignorant that I haven't even bothered to look at some documentation. I assure you this is not the case, and you were not being helpful, you were being condescending.

Comment: @Magnanimity whatever your experience and knowledge might be I don't care, but YELLING is not a good behavior, but I still don't care if think your experience and knowledge demands such things in a such a community.

Comment: Further from technical perspective,the first link was right on spot why you are missing the ajax HEAD on severside because, its not a standard and you plain js does not send it,  as describe in the answer and comments

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using vanilla ajax you need to pass the following header to your ajax request

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
```

Comment: Thank you, adding the request header solved the problem.